# Excel using a formula to check a condition and write the count

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have two columns Column M which has a set of details say server type and another column K which contains the alert types received. Now in the next sheet I want the result as check for the specific server type in column K and then to check for a specific alert and write the count of the number of times the a specific alert occurred.

```
Column K                 Column M
**Sub Component**        **Server Type**
Unknown                  Application Batch 1
CPU                      INC 4
Process                  ASSUMPTIVE 1
Filesystem               INFRA
Disk                     INFRA
FileSystem               INFRA
Unknown                  ASSUMPTIVE 1
FileSystem               ASSUMPTIVE 1
```

So the result am looking is:
In server `Infra` how many `Filesystem` alerts came (answer = 2)
In server `Assumptive 1` how many `Process` alerts came (answer = 1)

So like this for all the servers I need to know the count of the individual alerts received

Comment: Hard to say from your description but I would try using COUNTIF

Comment: can you advise how  to use, i dont need a pivot

Comment: all i need is first check for a name in a particular column and then in another column write the count of each alerts received

Answer (score 1):

Use `=Countifs()` formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,D2,A:A,E2)
```

Screenshot
[image]

You can also use `server type` and `alert type` as criteria of `=Countifs()` formula. See below...

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"INFRA",A:A,"Filesystem")
```

But this will return count result only for `INFRA` server type and `Filesystem` alert type.

Comment: As it will check more than 1 condition, so you have to use `=Countifs()` formula.

Comment: For eg the Sub component and Server type is in another sheet how to get the anser in a separate sheet

Comment: Suppose your results are in sheet2 and data are on sheet1. Then put the formula in `Sheet2` and refer `Sheet1` in formula like `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B:B,D2,Sheet1!A:A,E2)`

Comment: I already told you that earlier. This guy wants it all on plate!

Comment: Mark it as correct then. Although this answer is also worthy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull out the number of one specific alert, look into COUNTIF. If you want to count how many of each alert there are, look into Pivot Tables.

Comment: without Pivot i need the data

Comment: Anyone can answer with formuls

Comment: all i need is first check for a name in a particular column and then in another column write the count of  each alerts received

Comment: ...this is literally what pivot tables are for. This exact situation. This is what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edits and comments I would say you need something like:

```
=COUNTIF(a1:a10,"Filesystem")
```

That will tell you how many times Filesystem appears in that range. If you want it to look in another worksheet add 'worksheetname'! before the range.

```
=COUNTIF('sheet2'!a1:a10,"Filesystem")
```

EDIT - try this

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B8="filesystem")*(C1:C8="INFRA"))
```

Comment: it should also check the server name first and in that it should return the count

Comment: For eg check  the server type and then find for a specifc alerts count

Comment: Serer type No of Fatal alerts No of Unknown alerts count
Infra                      3                                1
Citrix-33              8                                0

Comment: OK try using SUMPRODUCT then. Ive edited my answer. This gives number of INFRA that appear in column c when filesystem is in column B.

Comment: Hi This works in a separate one but i have the data in one sheet and the result needed in another sheet

Comment: as it says above simply add 'sheetname'! before the range part.